# Lipschitz continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Show that $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2} +1}$ is Lipschitz conitnuous.

---

From the definition, we must show that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K|x-y|$, for some real constant $K$.

First, I tried to find:

$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^{2} +1} - \frac{1}{y^{2} +1}|=|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}| \leq \frac{(|x-y|)(|x|+|y|)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}$

Using the triangle inequality. However, I hit a dead end here. What would be the best way to approach this problem? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Notice that $$ \frac{|x|}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)} \leq 1, \qquad \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}.$$ Simlarly for $y$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to use that fact, but is it possible to prove it in a rigorous way?

Comment: Not yet, only until continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\frac{(|x|+|y|)}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\leq2.
$$
For $|x|$, $|y|\leq1$ it is obvious. If $|x|>1$, $x^2>|x|$, and $\frac{|x|}{1+x^2}\leq1$; similarly for $y$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right|&=\left|\frac{x+y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right| |x-y|\\
&\le \max\left(\frac{x+y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right)|x-y|\\
&={3\sqrt{3}\over 8}\,|x-y|
\end{align}
where the last equality follows from a little calculus.

Of course, we do not need such a sharp $K$, so we can of course estimate $$\left|\frac{x+y}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\right|$$ instead as outlined in other solutions.